# Is it possible to use XNU on GNU/Linux?

Tags: kernel, boot, apple

I was wondering whether it is possible to use the XNU kernel on a GNU/Linux system? But it would be, in effect, GNU/XNU. But is that possible? Does the kernel have sufficient drivers to boot on a lenovo? Or any computer other than a Mac? Or does the Apple EULA or AOSL deny my using it that way?

Answer (score 2):

This should involve some kind of emulation such as [linprocfs](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?linprocfs%285%29) that will allow you to run Linux binaries inside FreeBSD. I don´t think that such technology exists, where you will be able to run Linux binaries inside XNU.

However, you could give it a try on the [PureDarwin](http://www.puredarwin.org/) software distribution, that is a [Darwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29) compilation and it will allow you to user softwares like MacPorts. Quoting their goals:

> The goal of the PureDarwin project is to make Darwin more usable for open source enthusiasts and developers by providing documentation and by enabling them to retrieve, understand, modify, build, and distribute Darwin.

And there is an old project called [GNU-Darwin](http://www.gnu-darwin.org/) where they wrapped GNU software to Darwin,  but as you take a look to their site you will see that things are not being seriously developed.